# Copying file bytes from SD Card to FRAM

Tags: arduino, hex

I'm trying to copy a file from an SD card to an adafruit FRAM module.   I'm wondering if I'm going about it the right way. I'm trying to read the file one byte at a time and then write that byte to a specific location on the Fram module.

I've been trying that approach using the sketch below and haven't been successful. I'm wondering if I'm approaching it the right way, and if so, where have I gone wrong with my sketch. Thanks.

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_FRAM_I2C.h"
Adafruit_FRAM_I2C fram     = Adafruit_FRAM_I2C();
uint16_t          framAddr = 0;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);

// setup SD-card
Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
if (!SD.begin(4)) {
Serial.println(" failed!");
while(true);
}
Serial.println(" done.");

}

void loop() {
  uint16_t count = 0;

  File myFile = SD.open("test.txt");
  if (!myFile) {
  // if the file didn't open, print an error and stop
  Serial.println("error opening");
  while (true);
 }

 const int S = 1; 
 byte buffer[S];

 while (myFile.available()) {
// read from the file into buffer
myFile.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));


Serial.print("0x"); Serial.print(count, HEX); Serial.print(": ");

Serial.println(buffer[count]);

//write fram (address,value)
fram.write8(count,buffer[count]);


 }
 myFile.close();

 while (true) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't familiar with this FRAM, but you don't promote your address. 
So the device write to the same address all the time and rewrite the memory.

Hope i help.

yoav